# R ggplot, plot one column against another column in the dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple dataframe with 2 columns `date_booking` and `price` . I tried the simple default plot function:

`plot(codedf$date_booking,codedf$price)`

, which gave me this:

[image]

This is my first time using R and picked R for the plotting stuff. I learned ggplot provides better visualizations, so I installed it and just changed the above code to:

`ggplot( aes(x=codedf$date_booking,y=codedf$price) )`

which gave me this error : **ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval**

I thought this may be because my x axis is a datetime string and I didn't specify any conversion format. So I tried plotting only the price (against itself) , which is of type int:

`ggplot( aes(x=codedf$price,y=codedf$price) )`

And this again gave the same error.

What is the easiest way to plot one column against another in ggplot?

Comment: Please read up on ggplot2 syntax. It somewhat differs from the way we're used from base R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't pass in data.

```
?ggplot
# ggplot(data = NULL, mapping = aes(), ..., environment = parent.frame())

codedf<-data.frame(date_booking=seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), length.out=10, by="month"), price=1:10)
ggplot(codedf, aes(x=date_booking,y=price)) + geom_point()
```